# why did a mixture of water, sugar, starch effervesce after adding a little bit of glycerol as humectant? cooking at 130 degrees celsius

Tags: food-chemistry

I am trying a new formulation of lokum (turkish delight) which is a gel composed of starch, water and sugar. After adding 0.5% of glycerol to a 170 Kg of a boiling mixture, it became fugitive and effervesced. I need to know at which stage I should add the glycerol to the mixture. before cooking? or after I turn off the heat?

Comment: How can a mixture of water plus something bear a temperature of $130°C$ without being evaporated ?

Comment: You may want to ask this at https://cooking.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you add anything to a boiling mixture, you risk boiling over. Two possibilities present themselves: 1) the glycerol mixed with the formulation sufficiently to increase its viscosity and the boiling continued without the bubbles breaking.

But perhaps 2) the glycerol did not mix well, but spread over the surface of the hot formulation and cooled it, making this surface layer more viscous from the cooling rather than glycerol thickening. The lower layers continue to produce bubbles, but they don't break the surface.

Perhaps removing the formulation from the heat, allowing the bubbling to cease, and *then* adding the glycerol would work better.

Boiling after adding the glycerol could be a problem too. Don't they use glycerol in bubble-blowing formulations for children?

Anyway, use a big pot.